# Ordenar array de objetos traído del servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un archivo JSON que obtengo por medio de AJAX con un arreglo de eventos q contiene el nombre de ellos y la fecha. Se ve algo como esto (con más eventos):

```
{
  "fechaActual": "2019-01-01",
  "eventos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Nombre del evento",
      "fecha": "2018-12-12",
      "descripcion": "Descripcion del evento",
      "lugar": "Descripcion del lugar",
      "invitados": 20,
      "precio": 15
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Nombre del evento 2",
      "fecha": "2020-03-12",
      "descripcion": "Descripcion del evento 2",
      "lugar": "Descripcion del lugar 2",
      "invitados": 40,
      "precio": 25
    },
    // ... más eventos aquí
  ]
}
```

He intentado de varias maneras organizarlo de manera descendente, también definir los eventos en 3 parámetros, pasado, presente y futuro, en el JSON está la fecha del día de hoy, que los eventos pasados a esa fecha queden en la categoría pasado y los q son futuros a eso q quede en la categoría futura.

Éste es el código que muestra la información, pero sin orden:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "ruta-a-mi-json"
  }).done(function(info){
    $.each(function.eventos, function(index,obj){
      $(".lead").append("<li>"+obj.nombre+" "+obj.fecha+"</li>");
    });
  })
});
```

Y así se ven los datos en la página:

[image: captura de pantalla con una lista de elementos]

¿Cómo hago para organizar el array de manera decendente en JavaScript si es traído de un archivo JSON por medio de AJAX?

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor tómate tu tiempo para ver cómo hacer una buena pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hola, quizás [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888035/sort-jquery-ajax-json-foreach-data-by-date)  esta la solución a lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Código, por favor, no capturas. ¿entregas tus programas en capturas? No. Entonces procura poner el código para poder ayudarte. Puedes leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos